# AngularJs binding is delaying in directive

Tags: angularjs, binding, directive

Please see the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ThiagoRomam/1hyguh6n/

```
$scope.setDates = function(initialDate, finalDate) {
    $scope.initialDate = initialDate;
    $scope.finalDate = finalDate;
    $scope.apply();
};
```

When you press any key in the input or when you click the options (All Time, Today), the **apply** method is called before the binding can be done.

How can I fix that?

Comment: you don't need to use `$scope.apply();` there

Comment: The `apply()` is not `$apply`: `scope: { ... apply: "&fApply" } `

Comment: Although it wasn't the same method. It's good to know that I could be overriding wrongly an Angular method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the `$timeout` to wait for the `$digest` to finish. Check working demo: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1hyguh6n/5/)

```
app.directive("dateFilter", ['$timeout', function ($timeout) {
    ...
    $timeout(function () {
        $scope.apply();
    });
```

---

#### Suggestion

Do not use function name like `apply`, in case mix with the built-in function `$apply`.

Comment: it works! :D Also I rename the method in the initial scope to "applyMethod" and create a new "apply" method during linking using your suggestion. This way, calls made direct in html to "apply" will wait the $diggest too